# Behavior of a pair of integers under simple iterations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

The [originally asked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4087268/value-of-a-and-b-so-that-a-can-never-become-equal-to-b) was deleted by the OP for some unknown reason. I think this was a cute and interesting problem, and I'd really like to know the answer, so I'm just reposting the same question (with a little rewording).

Let's consider an initial pair of integers $(a_0,b_0)$ taken in the $\{1,1000\}$ range. Now we iteratively apply one of two simple transformations to such pair, either
$$
(a_n,b_n) \to (a_{n+1}=2a_n, b_{n+1}=b_n+1)
$$
or
$$
(a_n,b_n) \to (a_{n+1}=a_n+1, b_{n+1}=2b_n)
$$
Put in simple words, increment one of the elements of the pair, and simultaneously double the other one.

**Question**: does there exist a $(a_0,b_0)$ pair of integers such that there is no path leading to a pair of equal integers?

---

In a comment of the original question, I expressed the thought that an attack on the problem should probably take the binary representations of the integers into consideration. For instance
$$
\array{ 7 \texttt{ 111} \cr 5 \texttt{ 101}  } \to
\array{ 14 \texttt{ 1110} \cr 6 \texttt{ 110}  } \to
\array{ 28 \texttt{ 11100} \cr 7 \texttt{ 111  }  } \to
\array{ 29 \texttt{ 11101} \cr 14 \texttt{ 1110 }  } \to
\array{ 58 \texttt{ 111010} \cr 15 \texttt{ 1111 }  } \to
\array{ 59 \texttt{ 111011} \cr 30 \texttt{ 11110 }  } \to
\array{ 60 \texttt{ 111100} \cr 60 \texttt{ 111100}  }
$$
And in another comment, responding to Henry mentioning that he had not yet found a path to equality for $(15,22)$, I responded that there was a path to $123084$, outlining my process to find that path. Essentially, for
$$
\begin{array}{rl} 15 &\texttt{1111} \cr 22 &\texttt{10110}  \end{array}
$$
to have a chance to reach equality, we have to set to $1$ that second bit of $22$, and we need to do it as soon as possible, which means $8$ additions first to reach
$$
\begin{array}{rl} 3840 &\texttt{ 111100000000} \cr 30 &\texttt{ 11110}  \end{array}
$$
Now compensating for the length of the binary representation, we get to
$$
\begin{array}{rl} 3845 &\texttt{ 111100000101} \cr 960 &\texttt{ 1111000000}  \end{array}
$$
and with a final step
$$
\begin{array}{rl} 7690 &\texttt{ 1111000001010} \cr 961 &\texttt{ 1111000001}  \end{array}
$$
we show that we have transformed the problem from $(15,22)$ to $(10,1)$. And there's a path from $(10,1)$ to $(4,1)$, which resolves as shown above in the $(7,5)$ example (the same sequence of operations that brings $(28,7)$ to equality will work identically on $(4,1)$).

Comment: Is it correct to say that in manipulating the binary strings, we can always drop the longest common prefix of the two strings?  (If one string is a prefix of another, treat the resulting empty string as representing $0$.)  Wait.  I guess you don't want to be left with a string of $0$'s; it's not clear how to deal with that.  So, the longest common prefix that precedes a $1$ in each string.

Comment: I don't think so @saulspatz because in order for common prefixes to be meaningful both strings must have the same length

Comment: @saulspatz : I believe so, but in order to make sense, I think you need to keep a leading `1` somewhere in both representations, which is why I added that "final step" in my description. Oh, and perhaps needless for me to say, but I can't be sure that using binary representations is the fastest path to a solution of this problem. It's only my intuition.

Comment: @Jorge See how I edited my comment.

Comment: @user3733558 I agree.  That's why I edited my comment.  Does it look right now?

Comment: In the $(15,22)$ case, I had only looked as far as $25260$ so your $123084$ would have taken a little longer.  So the next question is whether in other cases you can always get your matching of the early digits as in $(28,7)$ and $(3840,30)$ in your two worked examples (I think you can) and then compensating for length (again possible but introducing new later digits) and sort out the later digits (not so obvious: perhaps you get into a loop - but even if you could construct a loop generator, how would you prove not other approach worked?)

Comment: @Henry I agree with you, and I follow quite exactly your train of thoughts here, having had the same ideas. So far, I can't find a proof, either way. It feels like there's a simple argument lurking behind this construct, just can't see it...

Comment: To check my understanding: when you say "we have transformed the problem from $(15,22)$ to $(10,1)$", do you mean that for practical purposes rather than a logical equivalence? There do seem to be sequences of operations that will eventually act differently on $(7690,961)$ and $(10,1)$—for example, the first transformation $2^{10}-961$ times.

Comment: @GregMartin : only for practical purposes, yes. Knowing a path to equality starting from $(4,1)$ means that we already know that $(28,7)$ will lead to equality (based on the truncation of its binary representation), using the same sequence of operations. And you are absolutely correct that this doesn't imply a strict equivalence.

Comment: @GregMartin There is more than one way to get from $(10,1)$ to equality: for example one reaching $(132,132)$ in ten steps, and another reaching $(204,204)$ in eleven steps.  The former does not work here (it breaks the prior "compensating for the length" when it adds $1$ to $15$) but the latter does work here because it never adds $1$ to get a power of $2$.  So this is a further complication.

Comment: Is this the same question as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766817/given-a-pair-of-integers-double-one-and-increment-the-other-until-equality)? It has been reposted several times recently, such as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4086520/choose-x-and-y-for-him-so-that-they-are-never-equal) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109197/find-x-and-y-so-that-they-are-never-equal)

Comment: @hgmath pretty much, yes. I paid attention while writing the question to the system's suggestions. I also tried searching with Google and ApproachZero. Sorry I missed that it already existed. How do you find these duplicates?

Comment: @hgmath: should I just delete, or someone will close the question soon?

Comment: @user3733558 I guess I googled "increment and double integers" or something like that when I came across the one of the linked duplicates (and now just stumbled on this question again...)

Comment: @user3733558 if you want you could delete it I guess, otherwise I could also flag it as duplicate

Comment: @hgmath I'm ok with both, but I hesitate to delete. I know the feeling of going back to a question I've bookmarked or otherwise participated in, and finding it 'disappeared'. If possible, I'd rather the others commenters find out what happened, so I suppose, please flag it?

Comment: @user3733558 ok I have :)

Comment: The question and commentary (including my own comments) mean that I now find [Project Euler 736](https://projecteuler.net/problem=736) relatively easy: many thanks